Sum up all the corresponding values from multiple mysql tables to one table
I have 8 mysql tables of same structure and with same headings. I want to add all corresponding values of all the 8 tables and store them in another 9th table.
Also i need to sum only till the lowest number of row of all the 8 tables.
For Eg. If there are 5 rows in table1 and other 7 have 6 rows each, then i only wamt to add upto 5 rows of all the 8 tables. Kinly provide a solution.
I am using php with mysql

Can you please remove the repeated content from your question and add a bit more detail. For instance an example of what the tables look like, what kind of data you want to sum, and what you have researched and tried. Where are you stuck?

There's no need to use PHP for this. You can sum your tables and write them to a another table all within the database using SQL.

Use UNION to combine all the tables into one table. SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2 ...

There is no relation to PHP as is. Please add more details if there is a relationship.
